# What happens on Ubuntu/Debian with user installed R packages during R upgrade

Tags: r, ubuntu, debian, upgrade

What happens with user installed R-packages during R-upgrade on Ubuntu/Debian?

The packages are installed in the libraries under /usr/lib/R/ and /usr/local/lib/R after giving the user write permissions for the folders.

I use the cran mirrors for upgrades and I am not sure if the user installed packages are transferred to the new version of R or if I have to reinstall them.

Best Wishes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `/usr/lib/R/library` and `/usr/lib/R/site-library` should *not* be user-writable. These are directories owned by the package management system, you get updated packages there just as always.

And by our setup, `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` can be made user-writable by users in a common group such as `staff`.  This is set up in the corresponding `postinst` script of the `r-base-core` package:

```
chown root:staff /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
chmod 2775 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
```

The idea is that several users can take care of these packages, and they *generally* just work after an updated---and many of us have been using this scheme successfully for years.

Right now, there is a minor issue with R 3.4.0 which stated in its NEWS file that

> - Packages which register native routines for .C or .Fortran need   to be re-installed for this version (unless installed with   R-devel SVN
>     revision r72375 or later).

That is a one-off, and particular to R 3.4.0. I have in fact reinstalled some of those packages in  the `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` directory tree.

Comment: Hi Dirk! Thanks for your answer! Really helpful. After an R upgrade I run update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE). Perhaps this should also be sufficient if newer R-version have problems with old packages?

Comment: One open point for me is the following:   You say that `/usr/lib/R/library` and `/usr/lib/R/site-library` should not be user writeable and is owned by the package management.  But what happens when I run `update.packages()` and R tries to update packages installed by the linux package management?  Then it needs write permissions to the folders or it will install in `~/` which results in different folders for different R versions. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Ah, good point. You have to say 'no' there. R "does not know" these packages come from `apt`  / `dpkg`.  One way around is to tell `upgrade.packages()` only to look in the `/usr/local/lib/R` path -- which is what my [`update.r` helper](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/update.r) does.